# Using python to connect to a SAS/IntrNet server

Tags: python-2.7, sas

I look for a way to access to data which are stored on a SAS/IntrNet database using Python. I don't find any information on the way to achieve it!

Currently, I access to data using a web viewer on a adress like :
http://remote.server/cgi-bin/broker.dll?_service=prod_sas9_ux&_program=prog.include.sas.

Is someone know a solution to access to the data using a python script ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the python requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.  This will allow you to call the SAS service via HTTP.

You will have to parse the results to build your python data structure